# What's the exact regex to match the proper string?

Tags: javascript, regex

My string has `[1212,1212],[1212,11212],...`

I'd like to extract each value into an array for example I'd want `1212,1212` as one pair and evaluate a series of steps.

Tried `/[[0-9],[0-9]]/` but It wasn't doing the task as I wanted. Basically I'm a noob in Regex, could someone please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you just need to match one or more digits before and after a comma, so you could do the following:

```
"[1212,1212],[1212,11212]".match(/\d+,\d+/g)
```

Which will give you the array: `["1212,1212", "1212,11212"]`

To extract the pairs:

```
var result = "[1212,1212],[1212,11212]".match(/\d+,\d+/g);

for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    var pair = result[i].match(/\d+/g),
        left = pair[0], right = pair[1];

    alert("left: " + left + ", right: " + right);
}
```

Comment: Both Sniffer and Matthew your codes worked. And thanks for it, but I chose this as the best answer because, it gave me one extra step that I wanted to drill down the left,right combo., which I din't do due to my laziness. 

Thanks all :)

Comment: Now I've another query. Does regex support Android native browsers? A part of my script which injects a DOM element based on the match obtained from the regexp match does not seem to work on Android or Dolphin browser on my mobile.

Comment: It should support regex if it supports javascript, there's probably a dom call that's not supported. Might be worth opening another question to solve this

Comment: Mathew, thanks a lot, but I had to debug in a different way to track the problem in the Android mobile.
The reason was that

if (condition)
  statement1;
  statement2;

worked in desktop browsers while in android the statement dint work, don't know what stopped it from working. After I enclosed the statements within braces, it started working like a charm!

Thanks a lot all of you :)

Answer (score 2):

You need some modifications for your regular expression for it to work correctly:

```
/\[[0-9]+,[0-9]+\]/g
```

1. You need to escape square brackets `[` because they have special meaning.
2. `[0-9]` matches only one digits, you need the `+` quantifier to match one or more digits and thus `[0-9]+`.
3. Use the global modifier `g` to extract all matches.

Then you can extract all the values into an array like this:

```
var input = "[1212,1212],[1212,11212]";
var pattern = /\[[0-9]+,[0-9]+\]/g;
var result = [];
var currentMatch;
while((currentMatch = pattern.exec(input)) != null) {
    result.push(currentMatch.toString());
}
result;
```

Or if you don't need to find the matches successively one at a time, then you can use [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Fmatch) as @Matthew Mcveigh did:

```
var input = "[1212,1212],[1212,11212]";
var result = input.match(/\[[0-9]+,[0-9]+\]/g);
```

Comment: Just wondering: is there any reason my edit was denied just so that you do the same edit yourself? Besides, I had also fixed a typo…

Comment: @IngoBürk Sorry but I am not the one who rejected/approved your edit, when I tried to see it SO told me that it was already dealt with and when I refreshed the page it was gone. Anyway if the typo is still there you are free to fix it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the literal brackets that you want to match. You can also use `\d` to match "any digit", which makes it tidier. Also, you're only matching one digit. You need to match "one or more" (`+` quantifier)

```
/\[\d+,\d+\]/g
```

That `g` modifier finds all matches in the string, otherwise only the first one is found.